# ATM interface design elements

Tags: design, ux-designer

Why are actions like cash withdrawal, pin change, mini statement kept on the right hand side of an ATM screen? (Most of the time)

Comment: "Always on the right" — could you post a photo of what you mean?

Comment: Always on right side of the screen? Not in my experience, at least in countries I visited.

Comment: Hey, changed question to mean 'most of the time' instead of 'always'.

Answer (score 1):

It is because of physical buttons. ATM screen were not always touch screens and physical buttons were required to operate the same. The easiest way to do that was to give physical buttons on Right side.

Case for not going with other sides:

Left: Well, [70 to 95% people are right handed](http://www.scientificamerican.com/article/why-are-more-people-right/). But still, many ATMs have physical buttons on left-side or both sides (same options as right-side in most cases to cover for both Left handed and Right handed people) but majority is right-side.

Top: Hand hides the screen (No mouse here) and same viewing angle as the the screen is not maintained.

Bottom: Viewing angle? Hierarchy?

So, the screens with right side navigation are either following the same convention or designers made it like that(might have theirs own reasons).

Note: Not all screens have right side navigation now as they are basically touch screens.

Comment: Talking about Indian ATMs in general, main actions like cash withdrawal, pin change and mini statement are always on the right hand side. Is there a design reason for that?

Comment: These options are usually linked with physical buttons, see https://laveti.files.wordpress.com/2012/11/atm.jpg

And, as I explained above, the best place to put physical buttons(directly related to scren elements) is the right side of the screen